# SQLAlchemy subquery not mapped to model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a `User` and a `UserConfig` model, a `User` can have many `UserConfig`, but only the last created `UserConfig` should be used. The rest are stored for historic references.

So my models look like this:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = mapped_column(String, primary_key=True)
    type = mapped_column(String, nullable=False)
    description = mapped_column(String, nullable=True)

    config = relationship("UserConfig")

    created_at = mapped_column(DateTime, server_default=func.now())


class UserConfig(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_config"

    id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    user_id = mapped_column(String, ForeignKey("user.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), name="user", nullable=False)
    user = relationship("User", back_populates="config")

    weight = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=False)
    meta = mapped_column(JSON, nullable=False)

    created_at = mapped_column(DateTime, server_default=func.now())
```

I now want to write a query which selects the `User`, and the latest `UserConfig`. This is what I currently have:

```
user_config_stm = session.query(UserConfig).distinct(UserConfig.user_id).order_by(UserConfig.label_id).order_by(desc(UserConfig.created_at)).subquery()
result = session.query(User, user_config_stm).where(User.id == id).join(user_config_stm, user_config_stm.c.user == id).first()
```

This however returns the following tuple: `(<apps.core.sql.models.user.User object at 0x11c904160>, 14, 'xxx', 12, '""', datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 29, 22, 52, 28, 860854))`.

I can't figure out why the results of the subquery are not mapped back to a `UserConfig` model. Ideally what I want is a tuple of `(User, UserConfig)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here was to use `aliased()`

```
user_config_stm = session.query(UserConfig).distinct(UserConfig.user_id).order_by(UserConfig.user_id).order_by(desc(UserConfig.created_at)).subquery()
user_config_alias = aliased(UserConfig, user_config_stm)
result = session.query(User, user_config_alias).where(User.id == id).join(user_config_alias, user_config_alias.user == id).first()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).